# Word to describe a _conduit_ that also _enriches_

Tags: single-word-requests

I am discussing a certain individual who both transmitted his tradition to future generations as well as made his own contributions to it. I am searching for a single word to describe an "*additive conduit*", that is, a passageway which contributes to whatever passes through it.

Comment: There is an Hebrew word _nachal_ conveying the concept of a river flowing and dividing. It denotes irrigation to the surroundings and also the dividing of tributaries, thus it is used in matters of inheritance. I cannot find an English equivalent, myself. So far.

Comment: Ironically, I was discussing inheritance of religious Jewish tradition from grandfather to grandchild and needed a word to describe the role of the grandfather who teaches and transmits.

Comment: Why not transliterate the Hebrew and make a new English word - nachal, without italics ? If we don't have it, we need it !

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments above, Hebrew has a word, *nachal*, and the circumstance is an Hebraic one.

*Nachal*, the verb, is translated, mostly, 'divide'.
*Nachal*, the noun, is a brook, flood, river, stream or valley.

The concept is, therefore, of flowing and dividing; covering an area with irrigation, supplying not just the immediate floodplain of the river but all that is below it, as the river divides and divides.

This concept is used metaphorically in *nachalah*, 'heritage', 'inheritance' and 'possession'.

It is a very strong concept in Hebrew tradition.

Why should one not, particularly in the above circumstance, transliterate the word nachalah (minus the italics) and bring it into English, for we appear not to have an equivalent that so imaginatively (as Hebrew is wont to do) expresses a concept in pictorial form.

I am taking all my information from the Young's Analytical Concordance.